# DAX - Return Latest Date that is Before Posting Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three tables. Purchase Invoice, Tax Area, Tax Jurisdiction. Sample data is in image.

Each **Purchase Invoice** record contains a [Tax Area]. Each [Tax Area] is made up of several [Tax Jurisdiction Code]s.

**Tax Jurisdiction** records each have an [Effective Date] and [Tax Rate]. When a [Tax Rate] changes for a [Tax Jurisdiction Code], a new record is added to **Tax Jurisdiction** with the same [Tax Jurisdiction Code] and a new [Effective Date]. The old record remains with the previous [Effective Date].

Based on the [Tax Area] field in **Purchase Invoice**, I need to return the sum of [Tax Rate] from **Tax Jurisdiction** for each unique [Tax Jurisdiction Code] included in the corresponding [Tax Area Code] in **Tax Area**. However, the [Tax Rate] returned for each unique [Tax Jurisdiction Code] needs to be the record with the latest [Effective Date] for that [Tax Jurisdiction Code] that is *on or before* the [Posting Date] from **Purchase Invoice**.

For example, for the highlighted record in Fig 1, it would need to return (1.9 + 3) as those are the rates for each [Tax Jurisdiction Code] within [Tax Area Code] = "CO-DELTA" that carry the latest [Effective Date] that is before the [Posting Date] of 12/23/2018.

In Fig 2, the highlighted record contains the same [Tax Area], but requires a different rate as new [Tax Rate]s went into effect for those same [Tax Jurisdiction Code]s.

Fig 1:

[image]

Fig 2:

[image]

I am at a total loss for how to accomplish this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you have (many to many) relationships set up between the tables:

[image: table relationships (Many to many)]

Now you can create your Effective Tax measure:

```
Effective Tax = 
VAR PostingDate =
    MAX ( 'Purchase Invoice'[Posting Date] )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        'Tax Area',
        CALCULATE (
            SUM ( 'Tax Jurisdiction'[Tax Rate] ),
            FILTER (
                'Tax Jurisdiction',
                'Tax Jurisdiction'[Effective Date]
                    = CALCULATE (
                        MAX ( 'Tax Jurisdiction'[Effective Date] ),
                        FILTER ( 'Tax Jurisdiction', 'Tax Jurisdiction'[Effective Date] <= PostingDate )
                    )
            )
        )
    )
```

Output for your sample data:

[image: sample output]

See https://pwrbi.com/so_56467693/ for worked example PBIX file